# Finding the counterclockwise nearest point in $\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$ time

Tags: algorithms

I am working on the following exercise:

> Given a point $q$, direction $w$ and point set $P$ with convex hull $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ known, give an
> algorithm to find the point in $P$ that $(q, w)$ touches first when rotated counterclockwise in $\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$ time.
>
> REMARK: We can assume that $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is sorted counterclockwise.

My idea would be the following: Since $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is sorted we can modify the approach of Binary Search to get the required $\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$ bound. I suppose we have to test the angles between $(q,w,v_i)$ repeatedly, but I do not see how to formulate this clearly. Could you help me?

Comment: Is it given that $q$ is inside the convex hull of $P$?

Comment: It is not stated, but I for the sake of simplicity I suppose we can assume that $q$ is not in the convex hull.

Comment: From the given formulation, it could be that $P$ contains any number of points, while having only a "small" number of it's point form the convex hull. In addition, nothing is given about those other points of $P$ not forming the boundary of the convex hull.

If only the points of the convex hull are to be considered, the answer of Hagen von Eitzen (just the first part) works. If all the points in $P$ are to be considered, it should be clear that there is no function of $n$ that can bound that algorithm's time, as there might be any (big) number of points in $P$, independent of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the orientation of $v_i-q$ vs. $w$, we can use the cross product (after viewing our $\Bbb R^2$ as subspace of $\Bbb R^3$). This amounts to checking the sign of the expression $$F(i):=(v_{i,y}-q_y)w_x-(v_{i,x}-q_x)w_y=(v_i-q)\cdot w^\perp$$
where $w^\perp=(-w_y,w_x)$ is $w$ rotated left by 90°.

All $v_i$ for which $F(i)$ is positive are on the same side ("ahead") of the line given by point $q$ and direction $w$, all $v_i$ with negative sign are on the other side ("behind"), and all with result $0$ are on the line itself.

If $q$ is inside the convex hull of $P$, we are looking for a change from negative to positive (or zero) sign along the cyclically ordered vertex sequence.
Binary search is fine as soon as we have obtained one $i$ with $F(i)<0$ and one $j$ with $F(j)\ge0$. Picking a random index will give us one of the signs, but it is not that trivial to find an index with the other sign. To do so, we may want to look for a maximizer or minimizer of $F(v_i)$. We may use that $F$ switches between increasing and decreasing only once. So start with $i=1$, $j\approx \frac 12n$, $k\approx \frac23 n$. If differnet signs occur at these, we are already done (up to the final binary search). So assume that $F(i),F(j),F(k)$ are all negative and we want to look for a maximizer (or similarly:  all positive and minimizer).
By perhaps using cyclic rearrangement of $i,j,k$, we may assume that  $F(i)<F(j)>F(k)$, i.e., the maximum among these three values is at the middle index. To facilitate distance calculations, I shall however assume that $i<j<k$.
Now we know that the maximizer is between $i$ and $k$. We can pick $l\ne j$ between $i$ and $k$ and thereby reduce our interval of length $k-i$ to an interval of length at most $\max\{k-l,j-i\}$ if $l<j$ or $\max\{k-j,l-i\}$ if $l>j$ by picking those three consecutive out of four indices that have the maximum in the middle again. The essential trick is to pick $l$ smartly so that the interval length decreases fast enough. Picking $l$ such that it split $[i,k]$ roughly by the Golden Ratio ensures this.